# Save image from bytes on client folder nodejs/typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm developing an application using node and typescript, I need consume an API that provide products and images of it, the images come as array of bytes, I can cath this array and save as file on client folder?

Have any library on nodejs that I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJs has [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) which is a built in function inside the fs(File System) module. If you are getting a image data in array of bytes, first you need to change it into array of buffer.

A typescript example:

```
import * as fs from "fs";

private getBufferFromBytes(imageBytes: number[]): Buffer {

let imageBuffer = new Buffer(imageBytes.length)
for(let b=0; b<imageBytes.length; b++) {
    imageBuffer[b] = imageBytes[b]
  }
return imageBuffer
}
```

You can now use the `writeFile` function to write to a file like this and pass your bytes array as parameter to the function that we created above:

```
fs.writeFile('yourFileName.jpg', getBufferFromBytes(imageBytes), err=>{
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Done writing image to file')
})
```